# Automatic disk check

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk

Ubuntu sometimes want to work automatic disk check and waiting press a key from me. But my computer is far away and hasn't a keyboard. I want to check automatic disk check without pressing a key. I'm using ubuntu 10.04. I know ubuntu does a disk check on every ~20 boots.  It is not a problem for me. My problem is waiting press a key from me for disk check. And so system is not booting until press a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [FSCKFIX=yes](http://www.howforge.com/how-force-fsck-ubuntu)

Comment: I don't want to start a disk check when next boot. As I say, Assume disk check will do next boot. While next booting ubuntu is waiting press a key from me and until I press a key ( I thing this is f and n ) computer doesn't boot. And I want to start disk check without press a key in this time.

Comment: ``FSCKFIX=yes`` does not force fsck; ``shutdown -F`` does. ``FSCKFIX=yes`` is to pass the appropriate flag to ``fsck``, so it automatically correct errors rather than prompting for a response